# can't install Tor. Now I can't use apt-get

Tags: apt, tor

```
You might want to run ‘apt-get -f install’ to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 tor-geoipdb : Depends: tor (>= 0.2.4.21-1~saucy+1) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I tried to install tor, it gave me an error & told me to use `apt-get -f install`, but now that won't work either. I just want to install TOR & get rid of the error :)

Comment: post the output of `sudo apt-get install -f` command on your question.

Comment: Here is the sequence of commands I use - http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/apt-get-how-to-fix-very-broken-packages/

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=HbfcXuCe
There you go.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen that doesn't work.

Comment: what does not work? what commands did you run ?

Comment: captain@captain-Root:~$ cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
captain@captain-Root:/var/lib/dpkg/info$  sudo rm flashplugin-nonfree.*
[sudo] password for captain: 
rm: cannot remove ‘flashplugin-nonfree.*’: No such file or directory
captain@captain-Root:/var/lib/dpkg/info$

Comment: captain@captain-Root:/var/lib/dpkg/info$ sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq flashplugin-nonfree
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove flashplugin-nonfree which isn't installed
captain@captain-Root:/var/lib/dpkg/info$  sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq realplayer
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove realplayer which isn't installed

Comment: you have to remove your tor packages, not flashpulgin packages

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The key line is:

```
trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/tor', which is also in package tor-browser 3.5.4
```

The error message indicates that a package called `tor-browser` is preventing you from installing the standard `tor` package.

Since `tor-browser` isn't in the standard Ubuntu repositories, I suggest you remove it from your system, then try `sudo apt-get -f install` again.